# RESTful jersey 404 not found

Tags: java, rest, maven, jersey, tomcat8

I am developing a ws with jersey and Tomcat8, the problem is that @path are not being processed, therefore the resultant URL is not working properly.

**Packages and classes description:**

*eu.datex and eu.datex2 packages* contain java classes with xml annotations for JAXB.

*Transformer class* converts xml data to java, this java classes are processed and saved in new datex2 object that will be returned ass http get in order to response with an XML.

*URL that does not work* localhost:8090/org.CTAG.DATEX2REST/rest/datex

Here I show you my mvn project structure and some important files.

**mvn structure:**

[image]

**This is ResourceConfig class:**

```
package com.CTAG.application;
import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;


@ApplicationPath("/rest")
public class MyApplication extends ResourceConfig {

    public MyApplication() {
        packages("com.CTAG.rest;");
    }

}
```

**web.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" version="3.1">
  <display-name>org.CTAG.DATEX2REST</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

  <display-name>CTAG DATEX2</display-name>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            com.CTAG.application.Init
        </listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```

This class initializes the conversion from a xml data(from server GET) to Java classes with JAXB:

```
public class Init implements ServletContextListener {

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
        System.out.println("ServletContextListener destroyed");
    }
    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent arg0) {
        System.out.println("----INITIALIZED----");
        try {
            Map<SituationRecord, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();

                URL url = new URL(" http://infocar.dgt.es/datex2/dgt/SituationPublication/all/content.xml");
                Map<SituationRecord, Integer> copia = map;
                map = Traslator.traslator(copia, url);
                System.out.println("----DATEX now available----");

                // Preubassleep(30000);

        } catch (TransformerConfigurationException | JAXBException | ParserConfigurationException | IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**Resource class(DataExchange)**, this has to returned a java class that will be converted to XML:

```
package com.CTAG.rest;


@Path("/datex")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
public class DataExchange {

    private D2LogicalModel datex2 = Traslator.d2;

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    public Response getDatex() {

        return Response.ok(this.datex2).build();
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/{road}")
    public Response getDatexByRoad(@PathParam("road") String roadName){

        SituationPublication payLoad = (SituationPublication)this.datex2.getPayloadPublication();
        FilterByRoad filter = new FilterByRoad(payLoad.getSituation());
        List<Situation> filteredList = new LinkedList<>();
        filteredList.addAll(filter.filterByRoad(roadName));
        payLoad.setSituation(filteredList);
        this.datex2.setPayloadPublication(payLoad);

        return Response.ok(this.datex2).build();
    }
```

Comment: what is your final war name?

Comment: What is `org.CTAG.DATEX2REST` part?

Answer (score 0):

Replace

{

```
packages("com.CTAG.rest;");
```

}

to

{

```
packages("com.CTAG.rest");
```

}

This would work.

Comment: Hi, thank you for fixing that mistake, but it`s still not working.

Answer (score 0):

This was solved using register() instead packages(), but I am not able to understand why, thank you.